# How to correct create a multilingual store Magento 2 with nginx?

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have server: ubuntu 16.04, nginx 1.10, MySQL 5.7, one installation Magento 2. And 2 domains: primary domain.com and domain.in for "in Store View".
My actions:
Create Store View "in".
Change my host config nginx insert:

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    domain.com default;
    domain.in in;
}
```

And insert to nginx.conf.sample:

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
```

So, now I have config:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    domain.com default;
    domain.in in;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.in;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com domain.in;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/domain.com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;

    location = /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/domain.com/html/robots.txt;
    }

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        alias /var/www/domain.com/html/sitemap.xml;
    }

    include /var/www/domain.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Result: not correct works, problem: closed access to the admin panel, when you change the language, it throws to the wrong domain.